# Web scraping data using Html Agility Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

Using Html Agility Pack, how can I get the string ABC from the html code:

```
<td><a data-quoteapi="$cur.symbol href=/asx/{$cur.symbol} (stockLink)" href="/asx/abc">ABC</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to get the element's InnerText. You are searching for a TD elements, so just ask HtmlAgilityPack to select such and you will find the html element's text within its `InnerText` property.

Based on your sample:

```
string html = @"<td><a data-quoteapi='$cur.symbol href=/asx/{$cur.symbol} (stockLink)' href='/asx/abc'>ABC</a></td>";

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var selectedElement = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("td");

if (selectedElement != null)
    Console.WriteLine(selectedElement.InnerText); //prints ABC
```